# How do I embed next.js with material-ui into keystonejs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, keystonejs

I'm trying to embed nextjs with material-ui into keystonejs.

I can get keystone to play nice with nextjs, no problem. https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/app-next/

And I can get nextjs to play nice with mui, no problem. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs

But, when I try to start keystone with the mui-ified nextjs, I get a react error related to [invalid hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

I tried the suggestions from that link (checking for multiple react/react-dom installations, or old versions, etc), and haven't found a smoking gun yet.

Any idea what extra step I'm missing to stitch this all together?

Here's where the two meet:

```
# cat index.js | tail -15

module.exports = {
  keystone,
  apps: [
    new GraphQLApp(),
    new AdminUIApp({
      enableDefaultRoute: false,
      authStrategy,
    }),
    new NextApp({
      dir: './nextjs',  // <--- fails when mui present, works without; cd'ing in there and starting with mui (directly, without keystone) works
    }),
  ]
};
```

Thanks!